# Как правильно парсить определенный текст-переменную в строке Java

Tags: java, парсер

Юзер вводит команду pref!log 12:30 normal aDDS

Мне нужно получить все что идет после `pref!log` и получить мне нужно данные такого формата:

```
String args1 = ? // тут должно быть 12:30
String args2 = ? // тут должно быть normal
String args3 = ? // тут должно быть aDDS 
                 //(Знак вопроса потому что я не знаю как парсить эти данные правильно)
```

И если юзер напишет уже команду с другими значениями, мне нужно чтобы все было так же само.
Получить я могу - `pref!log ? ? ?` (Там где знаки вопроса это значения), но как правильно парсить я не знаю, вот и суть вопроса.

Comment: Регулярные выражения можно использовать https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F или разбить строку по пробелу в массив и извлекать оттуда необходимые значения https://stackoverflow.com/a/7899558/407561

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если строка вида `pref!log ? ? ?`

Тогда можно так:

```
String str = "pref!log 12:30 normal aDDS";// это исходная строка  
String[] inputArray = str.split(" ");  
String args1 =  inputArray[1]; // тут должно быть 12:30  
String args2 =  inputArray[2]; // тут должно быть normal  
String args3 =  inputArray[3]; // тут должно быть aDDS
```